# jquery append div inside div wouldn't append to the end

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying an example found on a website, I want to keep all section, div, table, thead, tbody tags for formatting purposes. When I click the add link it could add the new `<div>` containing `<input type="text" name="names" value="2" />` on top of the old `<div>` containing `<input type="text" name="names" value="1" />`. This is not what I want, I want to add the new `<div>` below the old ones. I know this has something to do with the nested selectors, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Please help, thanks a lot in advance.

```
<section class="">
    <div class="container">
        <form name="addname" action="" method="post">'
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr class="header">
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <div class="thewrapper">
                        <div>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="names" value="1" />
                                </td>
                                <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addbutton">Add</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var maxrow = 10;
        var addButton = $('.addbutton');
        var wrapper = $('.thewrapper'); //Input field wrapper
        var field = '<div><tr><td><input type="text" name="names" value="2" /></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="removebutton" >Remove</a></td></tr></div>';
        var y = 1;
        $(addButton).click(function() {
            if (y < maxrow) {
                y++;
                $(wrapper).append(field);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Not sure if its a typo but it could be because you don't properly close the `wrapper` div you are appending to. I formatted the code in your question and you can see it. Some browsers will auto close a div when it finds no closing tag which would explain why you see appended stuff above.

Answer (score 2):

The reason its not working is because a `div` is not allowed to be a child of `tbody`. Some browsers try to fix that. In safari in jsfiddle its moving that `wrapper` div outside and above the table so when you append it is appending but its appending to a div thats been moved above the table. Hence why its looks like its prepending. Try something like this so you have legal HTML. Remove the wrapper DIV and the DIV around the the `tr` and just append to `tbody` without any DIV. Just directly append the `tr` to the `tbody`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yfhbe32s/

HTML

```
<section class="">
    <div class="container">
        <form name="addname" action="" method="post">'
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr class="header">
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="names" value="1" />
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addbutton">Add</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxrow = 10;
    var addButton = $('.addbutton');
    var wrapper = $('tbody'); //Input field wrapper
    var field = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="names" value="2" /></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="removebutton" >Remove</a></td></tr>';
    var y = 1;
    $(addButton).click(function() {
        if (y < maxrow) {
            y++;
            $(wrapper).append(field);
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: Cant really see what you posted in comment but try this for the remove. Basically it delegates the click event. We attach the click to the document and say that at some point there will be an element with the class `removebutton` and when clicked it should use the defined event handler. Delegated events are great for dynamic elements that may or may not be in the DOM at the time we attach the event. The event handler context (the remove button) then finds its closest `tr` parent and remove it and all its children and updates the counter as well.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yfhbe32s/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxrow = 10;
    var addButton = $('.addbutton');
    var wrapper = $('tbody'); //Input field wrapper
    var field = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="names" value="2" /></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="removebutton" >Remove</a></td></tr>';
    var y = 1;
    $(addButton).click(function() {
        if (y < maxrow) {
            y++;
            $(wrapper).append(field);
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.removebutton',
        function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            y--;
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: @user3043276 updated answer with remove. Hope it helps =]

Comment: Look at updated answer. Your issue is parent only finds its direct parent. Since this is the button, its parent is not tbody. And you don't want to remove the entire tbody anyway.

Comment: thank you so much for the quick responds. Now everything working great.

Comment: @user3043276 happy to help!! Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery's `appendTo()`, rather than `append()`. Read up on it [here](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

> The .append() and .appendTo() methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target. With .append(), the selector expression preceding the method is the container into which the content is inserted. With .appendTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted into the target container.

**Notice that I have switched your variables**

```
var maxrow = 10;
var addButton = $('.addbutton');
var wrapper = $('.thewrapper'); //Input field wrapper
var field = '<div><tr><td><input type="text" name="names" value="2" /></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="removebutton" >Remove</a></td></tr></div>';
var y = 1;
$(addButton).click(function() {
    if (y < maxrow) {
        y++;
        $(field).appendTo(wrapper);
    }
});
```

---

Also note that you're table HTML is incorrect. You're not allowed (at least it's not valid) to put other elements prior to the `<tr>` and `<td>`. You should really structure your HTML as so:

```
<tbody class="thewrapper">
    <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="text" name="names" value="1" />
         </td>
         <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addbutton">Add</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then in your jQuery:

```
var maxrow = 10;
var addButton = $('.addbutton');
var wrapper = $('.thewrapper'); //Input field wrapper
var field = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="names" value="2" /></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="removebutton" >Remove</a></td></tr>';
var y = 1;
$(addButton).click(function() {
    if (y < maxrow) {
        y++;
        $(wrapper).append(field);  // notice that I switched back
    }
});
```

This will take that variable, `field`, (which now starts with a `<tr>`, not a `<div>`), and `append` it to the `<tbody>` element.

Note that when you create your `event` for the `.removeButton` (I'm guessing that is going to remove the row), you need to use jQuery's `on` event, since it's created after `document.ready` has ran.

Comment: Except when they were using append the selector was the container they were inserting the content into.

Answer (score 0):

div is not allowed to be a child of tbody

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var maxrow = 10;
    var addButton = $('.addbutton');
    var wrapper = $('tbody'); //Input field wrapper
    var field = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="names" value="2" /></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="removebutton" >Remove</a></td></tr>';
    var y = 1;
    $(addButton).click(function() {
        if (y < maxrow) {
            y++;
            $(wrapper).append(field);
        }
    });

});
```